# Does an HP Deskjet 812c have an ink level check?

Tags: ink, hp-deskjet

I put a refilled ink cartridge into an HP Deskjet 812c. Now the power light is solid green, and the ink level light is blinking orange.  [HP says](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bud09169&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=58152#bud09169_OnOffBlinking) basically it is not recognizing one of the cartridges (although I cannot tell which; there is a color and a black). The Internet has procedures to reset the ink level of the cartridge, but I suspect the 812c is old enough it didn't track ink level. (By the way, [I tried](http://www.misterinkjet.com/hp45_15reset.htm) and it didn't work.)

Does the 812c need to have an ink level reset?
Can I tell which cartridge it thinks is out of ink?